# Convert mask (boolean) array to list of x,y coordinates

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 'mask' (boolean) 2D array and I would like to transform it into a list of coordinates. What's the proper numpythonic way to do that ?

The input would be something like this:

```
[[False,False,True],
 [False,True,False]]
```

and given the above input, the output should be:

```
[(0,2),(1,1)]
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use

- [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html): Can be used if you want to index another array later with it. But the result is not quite what you specified.
- [`np.argwhere`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html): If you want your specified result. But this result cannot be used for indexing another array.

Some example code:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[False,False,True],
              [False,True,False]])
np.argwhere(a) # equivalent to checking a == True
#array([[0, 2],
#       [1, 1]], dtype=int64)
np.where(a) # equivalent to checking a == True
#(array([0, 1], dtype=int64), array([2, 1], dtype=int64))
```

And if you want to convert your result to a list there is a `ndarray.tolist()` method. So you can call `np.argwhere(a).tolist()`.