# Remove [255,255,255] entries from list of image RGB values

Tags: python, list, image

I reshaped an image (included below) as a list of pixels, and now I want to remove the black ones (with value `[255,255,255]`). What is an efficient way to do it?

I tried using `IM[IM != [255,255,255]]` and I got a list of values, instead of a list of value triplets. Here is the code I'm using:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

IM = cv2.imread('Test_image.png')
image = cv2.cvtColor(IM, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# reshape the image to be a list of pixels
image_vec = np.array(image.reshape((image.shape[0] * image.shape[1], 3)))
image_clean = image_vec[image_vec != [255,255,255]]

print(image_clean)
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "remove"? An image has to have a value for every pixel in it or it won't be interpretable as an image any more. Do you mean you want an alpha mask for the image (making the black pixels transparent so you can "Photoshop" the eyes on to something). Or do you just actually want a contiguous list of the non-zero pixel values (like you're going to histogram them)? Or do you want a rectangular crop of the non-zero pixels (with enough zero pixels to make it a rectangle)?

Comment: Good question. I want to remove the `[255, 255, 255]` values from `image_vec`. I am fine with the fact that, after this operation, the array will no longer correspond to a 2D image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35340223/convert-mask-boolean-array-to-list-of-x-y-coordinates It seems like you're looking for `np.argwhere`.

Comment: You could consider `image_vec = im.reshape(-1,3)` instead the slightly awkward expression you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that numpy automatically does array-boradcasting, so using `IM != [255,255,255]` will compare each element to `[255,255,255]` and return a boolean array with the same shape as the one with the image data. Using this as a mask will return the values as 1D array.

An easy way to fix this is to use np.all:

```
image_vec[~ np.all(image_vec == 255, axis=-1)]
```